# Will the prince also officiate during the day of atonement in Ezekiel 45?

Tags: prophecy, ezekiel

In seems the prince will be the one offering sacrifices during the feasts,but nothing is mentioned of the day of atonement.

Ezekiel 45:17 (KJV)

> 17 And it shall be the prince's part to give burnt offerings, and meat offerings, and drink offerings, in the feasts, and in the new moons, and in the sabbaths, in all solemnities of the house of Israel:  he shall prepare the sin offering, and the meat offering, and the burnt offering, and the peace offerings, to make reconciliation for the house of Israel.

Ezekiel 45:21-23 (KJV)

> 21 In the first month, in the fourteenth day of the month, ye shall have the passover, a feast of seven days;  unleavened bread shall be eaten.   22 And upon that day shall the prince prepare for himself and for all the people of the land a bullock for a sin offering.   23 And seven days of the feast he shall prepare a burnt offering to the LORD, seven bullocks and seven rams without blemish daily the seven days;  and a kid of the goats daily for a sin offering.

Ezekiel 45:25 (KJV)

> 25 In the seventh month, in the fifteenth day of the month, shall he do the like in the feast of the seven days, according to the sin offering, according to the burnt offering, and according to the meat offering, and according to the oil.

Will the prince also officiate during the day of atonement

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I always find your questions to reflect a thoughtful examination of the scriptures. Kudos. You are inspiring me to dig deeper into Ezekiel's very unique visions.

Comment: @Ruminator,thank you,just love the word of God

Answer (score -1):

If Ezekiel 45 is referencing the millennial time period or the 1000 year reign of Christ, will there be a need for the Day of Atonement feast.  There is no reference to Feast of First Fruits, Feast of Weeks, or Feast of Trumpets in Ezekiel. These are fulfilled by the Second Coming of Jesus.  The Feast of Tabernacles is listed in Ezekiel 45:25 but not by name specifically with the same dates as listed in Lev 23:33-44.  Just a thought.

Comment: I think the question (and indeed the text) is about the day of atonement. There is njo mention (in either) of a 'millenial time period'. Your answer would need to substantiate your hypothesis (instead of assuming it).